# can we use multiple variables in foreach loop..?(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller

i want to use $news_data variable in my span tag that is under foreach loop.
this is my code..

```
 @foreach($news as $key => $value)
  <li>
     <a href=""> <h3 class="title">{{$value->title}}</h3></a>
     <div class="description">
     <div class="popup">
           <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
     <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"> **use $news_data here**</span>
     </div>
     {{$value->news_date}} : {{$value->description}}...
     </div>
 </li>
 @endforeach
```

this is my controller function:

```
public function index()
{
   $news = DB::table('feed_news')
           ->select(DB::raw('news_date,title,LEFT(`description`, 40) as 
             `description`'))
           ->orderBy('news_date','DESC')->get();
   $news_data = DB::table('feed_news')->select(DB::raw('description'))->get();
           return view('DisplayNews.index')
           ->with('news_data',$news_data)
           ->with('news',$news);
}
```

my $news & $news_data comes from controller.

what is the best way to do this..?

Comment: just put {{ $news_data }}

Comment: can you please show us what `$news_data` actually is? In another comment you say that it's an array. But how does it look, and what value would you like to access?

Comment: i want to show all description of news in span tag using $news_data, because my $news variable shows limited number of description.

Comment: can you please show the data you getting in ` $news_data`

Answer (score 0):

You can use different variables inside for loop, that doesn't belong to loop.
Just use that variable as any other variable:

Replace `**use $news_data here**` with

```
{{$news_data}}
```

Comment: shows error as htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: In that case you will have to do another loop inside your loop as it's array or call array index directly. As I don't know structure of your variable $news_data, if you post it, we can find out which way is the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">{{ json_encode($news_data) }}</span>
```

Above code will show all data of that `$news_data`

If you want to detail showing instead of showing all. Loop it again using `@foreach`

**To Show All**

```
   @foreach ($news_data as $newsDesc)
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">{{ $newsDesc->description }}</span>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: this shows me only first description data @foreach($news_data as $data)
   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">{{ json_encode($data) }}</span> @endforeach

Comment: @debrata just wondering. Did you do the code your self start from foreach ? if you do yourself, how can you meet this kind of problem'

Comment: thanks for your hellp!.. your above code displays first description properly but for second one it appends previous description.

Comment: @debrata hmmm.. you need to change it based on your need.. not me FEED SPOON everything of your need.. You are not even trying!

Comment: my span tag is a hover that pop's me up description of different news, your loop is correct, just help me why on hover of second news first news description is appending and on second news (1st & 2nd description) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a collection again in $news_data , hence you will have to loop it again to get it's description.

for example:

```
foreach($newsdata as $news)
{
    <span>{{$news->description}}</span>
}
```

Comment: `$news` is already used, use a different name for single newsdata items ;)

Comment: Yes, you can use any variable name. it was just an example.